# My code compiles on remix.ethereum.org but not on etherscan.io please help!

Tags: solidity, ether, etherscan, error, compilation

I get this error

> " ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration
>   expected.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool)
```

^ " everytime I try to verify my contract code. My ABI constructor parameters work fine.

I am using 0.4.20+commit.3155dd80
My contract address is 0x24b8ce20aeb2e68168e389bdb5f4b26bb77ac018

```
pragma solidity 0.4.20;

contract ERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
}

contract ERC223 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value, bytes indexed data);
}

contract ERC223ReceivingContract {
    function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) public;
}

contract Token {
    string internal _symbol;
    string internal _name;
    uint8 internal _decimals;
    uint internal _totalSupply = 1000;
    mapping (address => uint) internal _balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) internal _allowances;

    function Token(string symbol, string name, uint8 decimals, uint totalSupply) public {
        _symbol = symbol;
        _name = name;
        _decimals = decimals;
        _totalSupply = totalSupply;
    }

    function name() public constant returns (string) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public constant returns (string) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public constant returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _addr) public constant returns (uint);
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
}

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract LGCCoin is Token("LGC", "LGC-Coin", 2, 600000000), ERC20, ERC223 {

    using SafeMath for uint;

    function LGCCoin() public {
        _balanceOf[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    }

    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _addr) public constant returns (uint) {
        return _balanceOf[_addr];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
        if (_value > 0 &&
            _value <= _balanceOf[msg.sender] &&
            !isContract(_to)) {
            _balanceOf[msg.sender] = _balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
            _balanceOf[_to] = _balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
        if (_value > 0 &&
            _value <= _balanceOf[msg.sender] &&
            isContract(_to)) {
            _balanceOf[msg.sender] = _balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
            _balanceOf[_to] = _balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
            ERC223ReceivingContract _contract = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
            _contract.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isContract(address _addr) private constant returns (bool) {
        uint codeSize;
        assembly {
            codeSize := extcodesize(_addr)
        }
        return codeSize > 0;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
        if (_allowances[_from][msg.sender] > 0 &&
            _value > 0 &&
            _allowances[_from][msg.sender] >= _value &&
            _balanceOf[_from] >= _value) {
            _balanceOf[_from] = _balanceOf[_from].sub(_value);
            _balanceOf[_to] = _balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
            _allowances[_from][msg.sender] = _allowances[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
        _allowances[msg.sender][_spender] = _allowances[msg.sender][_spender].add(_value);
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint) {
        return _allowances[_owner][_spender];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/how on Etherscan are you trying to compile this? Can you give us the necessary steps to see the error?

Comment: The error is at line 7. Your line 7 is not that. What have you before the snippet of code you shared here?

Comment: On Etherscan I am trying to verify a contract code. When the compiler toys to compile the code it flattens it hence the line 7 not being what it looks like. @RickPark

Comment: Trying to verify contract code @smarx

Comment: @JesseBusman any help you could give

Comment: That's really not enough info to reproduce the error. E.g., there are multiple tools for verifying contracts on Etherscan, and there are quite a few parameters, and you haven't told us the network you're on or the address of your contract.

Comment: @smarx contract address is 0x24b8ce20aeb2e68168e389bdb5f4b26bb77ac018

Comment: It seems like information about this question is going to be too hard to get. I'm voting to close.